# Making a $lookup query between two collection on the ObjectId field

Tags: mongodb, go, mongodb-query, mgo

I'am working on an api in `Go 1.9.2` with `mongoDB 3.4` I am using `mgo` as a driver.

I have to do an endpoint for getting the results of the requests, after inserting the request and its results in the same database with two collections.

Having two collections:

First  Collection  : `requests`

Second Collection  : `results`

The `requests` collection has the format

```
{ "_id":ObjectId("5afc034f53c9a77a598c8345")
  "  time ":"2018-05-16 10:08:35.024352907 +0000 UTC m=+23.407317980"
  "param_request":[name:"mike",age:"30",job:"Doctor"]
}
```

The `results` collection has the format the `id_request` field is the `_id` field for the request document (as the foreign key philosophy in SQL)

```
{"_id":ObjectId("5afc035b53c9a77a598c8346")
 "id_request":ObjectId("5afc034f53c9a77a598c8345")
 "name":"Mike"
 "age":"30"
 "job":"Doctor"
 "city":"Tokyo"} 

{"_id":ObjectId("5afc035b53c9a77a598c8347")
 "id_request":ObjectId("5afc034f53c9a77a598c8345")
 "name":"Mike"
 "age":"30"
 "job":"Doctor"
 "city":"London"}


 {"_id":ObjectId("5afc035b53c9a77a598c8349")
 "id_request":ObjectId("5afc034f53c9a77a598c8345")
 "name":"Mike"
 "age":"30"
 "job":"Doctor"
 "city":"Berlin"
 }
```

I tried to query and I found the lookup from the documentation [$lookup Documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#pipe._S_lookup)

the result wanted :

```
 {
 "name":"Mike"
 "age":"30"
 "job":"Doctor"
 "city":"Berlin"

 }

 {
 "name":"Mike"
 "age":"30"
 "job":"Doctor"
 "city":"London"

 }

 {
 "name":"Mike"
 "age":"30"
 "job":"Doctor"
 "city":"Tokyo"

}
```

Here is what I did:

```
 db.results.aggregate([

  {$lookup: {from:requests, localField: "id_request",foreignField:"_id",as:”results”}},
  {$match:
         { 
      "id_request": ObjectId("5afc034f53c9a77a598c8345") }}]);
```

here is the error getting :

`2018-05-16T11:31:51.261+0000 E QUERY    [thread1] SyntaxError: missing } after property list @(shell):1:131`

Here is what I have to get with the SQL philosophy as a query:

```
  select results .* from results join requests on 

  (results.request_id=requests._id 

               and 

    request_id='ObjectId("5afc034f53c9a77a598c8345")');
```

Comment: Getting help means being a bit more descriptive than *"but is not working."*. Tell us exactly what is not working and what you expect. What you expect is not expressed as "what this SQL does", but rather by showing results you expect to return from the data you actually have.

Comment: @NeilLunn what the `query made in mongodb` is giving me all the results i have for all the requests , what i excpect is what i have written as `SQL query` which i am familiar `with so adding the condition of request_id  to be matched with the value `

Comment: I think all you want to do is add a second stage after the `$lookup` stage like this: `{$match: { "id_request": ObjectId("5afc034f53c9a77a598c8345") }}`

Comment: ...or you might want to flip the `$lookup` direction like so: `db.requests.aggregate([{
    $lookup: {
        from:'results', 
        localField:"_id",
        foreignField:"id_request",
        as:"results"
     }
}]);`

Comment: @dnickless i did what you suggested but it is getting me the error i edited the question , may you check please , moreover i added more details , thanks for your time

Comment: Why do you use `$lookup` if all the data you need is in the `results` collection anyway? You could do a straight `db.results.find("id_request": ObjectId("5afc034f53c9a77a598c8345"))`

Comment: @dnickless  i see what you mean but the purpose was to select the fields wanted  between the two collections

Answer (score 0):

The query in your question has multiple issues which may cause parsing errors. The `from` property in the lookup stage must be a string. Also, the quote character that you used for the `as` property (`”`) is not a valid string delimiter.

Try to replace the `from: requests` with `from: "requests"` and the `”` character with a single or double quote.

```
db.results.aggregate([
   { $lookup: { from: "requests", localField: "id_request", foreignField: "_id", as: "results" } },
   { $match: { "id_request": ObjectId("5afc034f53c9a77a598c8345") } } 
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you add two extra steps to your pipeline, $unwind and $project, you should get the results you want. I would also do the $match before the $lookup, you might as well only lookup the data you need.

I am also a fan of making your pipeline query easy to read by defining separate queries and combining them in the pipeline call. You asked this question as a Go question, so a Go way of doing it is:

```
match := bson.M{"$match": bson.M{"id_request": bson.ObjectIdHex("5afc034f53c9a77a598c8345")}}
lookup := bson.M{"$lookup": bson.M{"from": "requests", "localField": "id_request", "foreignField": "_id", "as": "results"}}
unwind := bson.M{"$unwind": "$results"}
project := bson.M{"$project": bson.M{"_id": 0, "name": 1, "job": 1, "age": 1, "city": 1}}

iter := theCollection.Pipe([]bson.M{match, lookup, unwind, project}).Iter()
answer := bson.M{}
for iter.Next(&answer) {
    fmt.Println(answer)
}
iter.Close()
```

Comment: here i have the `request_id` from the result collection`  and the `_id` from `the request collection `, for the iteration `theCollection` should be the request or the result , i tried both but i just get a blank result ,